# Authentication lost Google app script

Tags: authorization

I have created a a google app script that create a pdf from a google sheet and send it via email.

I have three script that work perfectly. But with the fourth script (identical to the other)I lost always the authorization after about one - two hours.

Has someone the same problem?

Thanks

Pasquale

Comment: Can you provide some code? No one can figure out what is wrong in your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Attached code. I use a trigger to lunch code every time the form is submitted.

```js
// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
var docTemplate = "1mI4SQQe4muuW386jgzkxBlZBWuH0OBRdbz1hItOPjK4";  
var docName = "DDT";  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HzZFDJYAU6H1pptqcA5fEAVelkZw1LP7si9bBrsF_u0")
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
var d = new Date ();
var id ="0B1-7TPSHWZ1bMlNLTV9tTFJNb2c"; // cartella Raccolta DDT
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
//Get information from form and set as variables
  //var email = "pasquale.martucci@decathlon.com";
  
  var email = e.values[1];
  var mittente = e.values[2];
  var destinatario = e.values[3];
  var primaQnt = e.values[4];
  var primaDescr = e.values[5];
  var secondaQnt = e.values[6];
  var secondaDescr = e.values[7];
  var terzaQnt = e.values[8];
  var terzaDescr = e.values[9];
  var quartaQnt = e.values[10];
  var quartaDescr = e.values[11];  
  var quintaQnt = e.values[12];
  var quintaDescr = e.values[13];
  var aspetto = e.values[14];
  var colli = e.values[15];
  var peso = e.values[16];
  var vettore = e.values[17];
  
// Ricava indirizzi e città
  
 var cell1 = sheet.getRange("S"+lastrow);
 cell1.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(C"+lastrow+";Foglio2!A1:C35;2;FALSE)"); 
 var indirMitt = cell1.getValue()
 var cell2 = sheet.getRange("T"+lastrow);
 cell2.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(C"+lastrow+";Foglio2!A1:C35;3;FALSE)"); 
 var citMitt = cell2.getValue()
 var cell3 = sheet.getRange("U"+lastrow);
 cell3.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(D"+lastrow+";Foglio2!A1:C35;2;FALSE)"); 
 var indirDest = cell3.getValue()
 var cell4 = sheet.getRange("V"+lastrow);
 cell4.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(D"+lastrow+";Foglio2!A1:C35;3;FALSE)"); 
 var citDest = cell4.getValue()
 
//Ricava data 
 var day = sheet.getRange("W"+lastrow);
 day.setFormula("=(DAY(A"+lastrow+"))");    
  var month = sheet.getRange("X"+lastrow);
 month.setFormula("=(MONTH(A"+lastrow+"))");  
   var year = sheet.getRange("Y"+lastrow);
 year.setFormula("=(YEAR(A"+lastrow+"))"); 

 var day1 = sheet.getRange("W"+lastrow).getValue(); 
 var month1 = sheet.getRange("X"+lastrow).getValue();  
 var year1 = sheet.getRange("Y"+lastrow).getValue();  
  
var data = day1+"/"+month1+"/"+year1;
  
  
// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Docâ€™s id
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
                .makeCopy(docName+' N° '+lastrow+' ' +mittente , folder)
                .getId();
// Open the temporary document
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the documentâ€™s body section
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  
// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template  
   copyBody.replaceText('keyMittente', mittente);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDestinatario', destinatario);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyQNT1', primaQnt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDescrizione1', primaDescr);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyQNT2', secondaQnt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDescrizione2',secondaDescr);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyQNT3', terzaQnt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDescrizione3', terzaDescr);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyQNT4', quartaQnt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDescrizione4', quartaDescr);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyQNT5', quintaQnt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyDescrizione5', quintaDescr);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyAspetto', aspetto);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyKg', peso);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyColli', colli);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyVettore', vettore);
  
   copyBody.replaceText('keyIndirMitt', indirMitt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyCitMitt', citMitt);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyIndirDest', indirDest);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyCitDest', citDest);
  
   copyBody.replaceText('keyNum', lastrow);
   copyBody.replaceText('keyData', data);
  
// Save and close the temporary document
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  
// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
  
// Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "DDT";
   var body    = "In allegato il DDT generato tramite il portale SimplyCar.";
   GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 
  
// Delete temp file
  // DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```